# Create Array Input field in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using `Angular 6`.

I have more than 100 items in an array which I have to display in a table. The first element of the table is the checkbox to select the field.

For that checkbox input field I have created a `formGroup`

```
exportForm: FormGroup;
processedItems: Array<any> = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.exportForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      product_index: new FormControl([])
    });
}
```

and in template

```
<form [formGroup]="" method="post" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let p of processedItems; let id = index">
      <td>
        {{ id+1 }} <input class="" type="checkbox" formControlName="product_index" title="select" value="{{ id }}">
      </td>
      <td> {{ p.title }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**onSubmit()** handler.

```
onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.exportForm.value);
}
```

But this only gives one item with `false`

[image]

I want to get `value` of the selected checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
onSubmit() {
  const selectedOrderValue = this.exportForm.value.product_index
      .map((v, i) => v ? this.processedItems[i].value : null)
      .filter(v => v !== null);
}
```

Ref This:https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular

Comment: `console.log(selectedOrderValue)` is giving a blank array with length 0. I'm afraid if I'm doing it correct?. In the reference example there are predefined values and `*ngFor` is iterating throw those values. I do not have values to set to form instead want multiple input fields with blank value to the size of the `processedItems`.

Comment: I saw the example and want exactly same as it is. But I do not have data to create `controls`.

Comment: Then how are you populating the check box

Comment: you can see implementation in the question.

Comment: why are you using formControl instead of formArray do you have any specific reason?